# How do Paradise Plume and Defiant Bloodlord interact if the first spell mentioned is used to cast the second

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

[Paradise Plume](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Paradise%20Plume) allows the caster to choose a color, spend a mana of chosen color, and whenever a spell of that color is played the controller may gain 1 life.
[Defiant Bloodlord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Defiant%20Bloodlord) is a creature that states whenever the controller gains life, target opponent loses that much life.

My question: If I use Paradise Plume to cast Defiant Bloodlord (results in gaining 1 life), does the 1 life gained from using Paradise Plume to play Defiant Bloodlord trigger Defiant Bloodlord to make an opponent lose 1 life? Or is the life gained prior to Defiant Bloodlord entering the battlefield, resulting in no trigger?

Answer (score 4):

The latter. By the time Defiant Bloodlord enters the battlefield, the Paradise Plume effect will have triggered already.

- You cast Defiant Bloodlord, tapping Paradise Plume
- Paradise Plume's ability goes on the stack above Defiant Bloodlord
- The last item in resolves first, so you gain 1 life. Defiant Bloodlord is still on the stack ("in the process of being cast")
- Defiant Bloodlord resolves and enters the battlefield

By the time Defiant Bloodlord enters the battlefield, Parasdise Plume's ability is no longer there, because it has already resolved. So your opponent doesn't lose 1 life.

One of the rulings for Paradise Plume makes it clear that you gain the life before Defiant Bloodlord resolves:

> An ability that triggers when a player casts a spell resolves before the spell that caused it to trigger. It resolves even if that spell is countered.

If the ordering were different then yeah your opponent would lose 1 life.